# In universe, who wrote/performed "Everything is Awesome"?

Tags: lego, lego-cinematic-universe, the-lego-movie, the-lego-movie-2-the-second-part

I have yet to see *The Lego Movie 2: The Second Part* so I am not sure if it answered there and I can't remember it being answered in *The Lego Movie*.

Who, in universe, wrote and performed the hit song "Everything is Awesome"?

Comment: This question is awesome.

Comment: @Snow Your comment is awesome.

Comment: The OP is awesome.

Comment: The first movie implies that Octan produces the popular music as part of their control over the mass populace, also - Wyldstyle is shown to hate the popular music, calling Batman's music "real" music: script excerpt: "Emmet Brickowoski: President Business is gonna end the world? But he's such a good guy! And Octan... they make good stuff; music, dairy products, coffee, TV shows, surveillance systems, all history books, voting machines... Wait a minute."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since my below answer LEGO have released some of the minifigures for *The Lego Movie 2: The Second Part* and one of them is named [Flashback Lucy](https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/minifigures/characters/flashback-lucy-4c57ffabf58b4e099a0ae8f3e494cc40).

> This singing sensation from The Popular Band recalls a time when everything really was awesome, until she discovered that it wasn’t – but the rhythm isn’t going to get her!
>
> [image: Flashback Lucy minifigure]

As we can see Lucy was one of the artists for the original recording of Everything is Awesome and the description notes that she was a part of the group called "The Popular Band".

---

According to Wikipedia and the Fandom wiki it is revealed in *The Lego Movie 2: The Second Part* that Lucy used to have a band and was in fact [one of] the original singers for "Everything is Awesome". Whilst this doesn't give evidence that she and/or her band wrote the song it could be true that they did.

> Emmet's dream house is rebuilt and Lucy reveals that she was one of the original artists of "Everything is Awesome" as Emmet gasps in response.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia, *The Lego Movie 2: The Second Part*, Plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lego_Movie_2:_The_Second_Part)</sub>

> She used to have a band & was the original singer for Everything Is Awesome.
>
> <sub>[The Lego Movie Wiki, Lucy, Trivia](https://thelegomovie.fandom.com/wiki/Lucy)</sub>

In *The Lego Movie* it is implied that Octan produced the music as [NKCampbell commented on the question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205383/in-universe-who-wrote-performed-everything-is-awesome#comment561376_205383).

> **Emmet Brickowoski:** President Business is gonna end the world? But he's such a good guy! And Octan... they make good stuff; music, dairy products, coffee, TV shows, surveillance systems, all history books, voting machines... Wait a minute.
>
> <sub>*The Lego Movie*</sub>

Comment: Given every other name in that draft was changed, I'm not sure it carries much weight.

Comment: @OrangeDog Like I said almost certainly not canon but certainly worth a mention.

Comment: This answer is awesome.

Comment: I believe in the second film, the poster Lucy shows says "Popular band" (as in, that's how they're called).

Comment: I've added spoiler tags since this isn't revealed until the very end of the movie and is relevant to the character's story arc.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez I haven't seen it yet so can't confirm but I'll try and track something down such as an image. Thanks for the heads up.